# can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64 bit platform

Tags: java

I have a Windows 2003 64 bit terminal server which we run a Java application from. The application has always worked up until 2 days ago. No new updates have been installed to the server in that time frame. I have tried re-installing java 64 bit but still have the following error.

```
Unexpected exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
**Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\19\625835d3-5826d302-n\swt-win32-3116.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.init(Device.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.init(Display.java:1784)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:359)
    at com.ko.StartKO.main(StartKO.java:57)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [comment](https://serverfault.com/a/332479/17794) on the other answer,

The issue was fixed by uninstalling 64 and 32-bit Java and then only re-installing 32-bit Java.

(Moving user101425's comment to an answer as he seems unlikely to return)

Answer (score 0):

**"Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"**

Something's changed.

Try:

- clearing the cache
- locating the 64-bit version of that DLL
- Restoring from backups to see what's changed

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by uninstalling Java 32 bit and 64 bit and then just re-installing Java 32 bit. Thanks for the help.